# Android layout with equal spacing between elements

Tags: android, xml, gui, layout

I am trying to make a nice set of items, which are equally spaced from each other. 
On example below, I set buttons between empty textview. Every button and text view has `height = 0dip` and `weight=1`. And it looks pretty nice. However, is there a way to clean up the layout file?

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_distance_walked"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Distance walked = " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_exersise_time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Exercise time = " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_average_speed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Average speed = " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_calories_burned"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Callories burned = " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_back"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Back" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add some screenshot of how this looks for you?

Comment: If you need both buttons and TextViews then this seems good!

Comment: It will look best if you use ListView with some style instead of TextView and set the property for divider in ListView as per requirement and it will look great.

Comment: How do you make a GUI description more efficient? I don't get it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android's process, but could you use theming or styles to prevent duplication of height, weight and wrap values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know what the standards are for Layout Naming on Android, but I can tell you that these names are not very good.

- `textView2`
- `btn_distance_walked`
- `textView3`

none of these accurately describes what they do.

you should probably look for naming schemes on Google.

`btn_distance_walked` doesn't tell us what the button is going to do. What is it going to do with the distance walked? It should be something like `calculate_Distance` or `calculateDistance` (my preferred naming scheme camelCasing)

***Update:***

I recently answered a question similar to this one and came up with a name scheme for buttons, `action_ObjectActedUpon`  this may be more specific to the naming issue in your code as well.

---

Your indentation seems to be off as well, it should look like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_distance_walked"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="Distance walked = " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_exersise_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="Exercise time = " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_average_speed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="Average speed = " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_calories_burned"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="Callories burned = " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

I just answered a similar question and I think that I should add a little bit of that answer to this one..

Another way that you can reduce clutter in the layout is to define some styles by creating an xml file in the `res/values/` folder of your project and do this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyStyle1">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <!-- etc. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

and then in your Layout XML you add the style to the layout element like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/MyStyle1"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        style="@style/MyStyle1"
        android:id="@+id/btn_distance_walked"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="Distance walked = " />

    <TextView
        style="@style/MyStyle1"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        style="@style/MyStyle1"
        android:id="@+id/btn_exersise_time"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="Exercise time = " />

    <TextView
        style="@style/MyStyle1"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        style="@style/MyStyle1"
        android:id="@+id/btn_average_speed"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="Average speed = " />

    <TextView
        style="@style/MyStyle1"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        style="@style/MyStyle1"
        android:id="@+id/btn_calories_burned"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="Callories burned = " />

    <TextView
        style="@style/MyStyle1"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        style="@style/MyStyle1"
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:text="Back" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/MyStyle1"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

note that I am not a professional, but I found [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) from doing a quick search for `styles.xml android example`

Don't forget about [Developer.Android.com](http://developer.android.com/) it can be very helpful.